# Application Crashing in Splash Screen on Android 12

Tags: java, android, splash-screen, android-12

Our app (live in playstore with over 10k downloads) has new Android 12 users who are facing crashes with custom splash screen activity where it is just checked if the user is logged in. The only possible reason for this crash can be the new Splash screen api introduced in Android 12. But even after integrating it, this does not workon android 12 mobile phone. Please help me navigate the problem in my code below.

I am using the library:

> implementation 'androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.0-alpha02'

At splash.xml:

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.App.Starting" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@drawable/appback</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/applogo</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.AppName</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Declared theme at both application level and activity level using:

> android:theme="@style/Theme.App.Starting"

In my home screen (User cannot visit homescreen without logging in), just above set contentView:

```
splashScreen.setKeepVisibleCondition((SplashScreen.KeepOnScreenCondition) () -> {
            if (user_id.equals("")){
                startActivity(new Intent(context,LoginActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
            return true;
        });
```

Comment: Do you have crash message or stack trace?

Comment: it is working from Nogoat to Android 11. The app just stops without showing anything or recording crashes in Crashlytics. I cannot usb debug as I don't have Android 12.

Comment: Have you tried emulator with API 31?

Comment: Yes Actually due to device limitations the emulator is not starting that is why unable to test there. Did you see any problem with my code?

Comment: I assume you used `installSplashScreen(Activity)`?

Comment: Yes I did use installSplashScreen

Comment: Error while Launching activity is the message shown while running on emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This attribute has to be a color, not a drawable (unless your drawable is a color)

`<item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">@drawable/appback</item>`

Comment: Thanks alot it really help me solve the issue!